# jdbc class not found spring mvc

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jdbc

Hi everyone I'm developing a web application with spring and hibernate and when I try to run it I get an exception jdbc class not foud but I added Jdbc-connector to pom.xml

```
<annotation-driven />
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="datasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.jdbc.mysql.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gestion_bp" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="root"/>
    <beans:property name="password" value=""/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
    <beans:props>
        <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
        <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
        <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect" >org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</beans:prop>
    </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.sqli.bap" />
<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</beans:bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<beans:bean id="PersonneDaoImpl" class="com.sqli.bap.daoImpl.PersonneDaoImpl"/>
<beans:bean id="PersonneMetierImpl" class="com.sqli.bap.metierImpl.PersonneMetierImpl"/>
```

Pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Common pool -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>Commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>Commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>Commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>Commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- MYSQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

exception

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.jdbc.mysql.Driver'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1429)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:450)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1775)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:247)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong
Thanks a lot

Comment: The error is quite clear ... `Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.jdbc.mysql.Driver'` should tell you enough... Hint, check the classname, another hint switch `jdbc` and `mysql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using

```
<beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.jdbc.mysql.Driver" />
```

But it must be

```
<beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
```